# ERROR: trackEvent: properties must of MoEProperties type in moengage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, moengage

I have set up moengage in reactJs and it's working perfectly.Now when I try to setup moengage with react native, I am facing issue to track event. when I try to make a event it gives below error

[This is  the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jvyf.png)

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you in advanced.